# hrulefill center text

Tags: boxes, rules

So I am trying to center my text across the center of the `\makebox`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
    \makebox[2in]{\hrulefill\rlap{John Doe}\hrulefill}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Right now, the text is starting to appear at the center of the `\makebox` instead of being centered at `\makebox`'s center. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\rlap` produces a box of width 0 the left "anchor" of which is aligned with the current position. You need something that aligns the center of the current position. You can use either `\makebox[0pt]{...}` (or `\makebox[0pt][c]{...}`), or `\clap{...}` from the `mathtools` package for that.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill\rlap{John Doe}\hrulefill}

\noindent\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill\makebox[0pt]{John Doe}\hrulefill}

\noindent\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill\clap{John Doe}\hrulefill}
\end{document}
```

[image]